# The text on the textureview is not smoothed

Tags: android, android-textureview

I draw text in a TextureView by adding to the canvas. But the text is not smooth. 
Lines and other shapes are fine. Anti-Aliasing added.
[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nDwBX.jpg)

```
DrawThread(ISurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, Context context) {
    this.surfaceHolder = surfaceHolder;
    fontPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    fontPaint.setTextSize(TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 36, context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics()));
}

@Override
public void run() {
    Canvas canvas;
    while (running) {
        canvas = null;
        try {
            canvas = surfaceHolder.lockCanvas();
            synchronized (surfaceHolder) {
                if (canvas == null)
                    continue;
                drawPath(canvas);
            }

        } finally {
            if (canvas != null) {
                surfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);
            }
        }
    }
}

private void drawPath(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawText(number, 500, 500, fontPaint);
}
```

Comment: show the code please

Comment: Maybe you need to use [`setFilterBitmap`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setFilterBitmap(boolean))?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce Not working for me

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko Attached to the post